# Create a repository with sub-repositories

Tags: git, github

I want to create a repo that has sub-repositories, to do that I created a `sample` folder in my workspace:

```
$ cd ~/workspace/
$ mkdir samples
$ cd samples
$ pwd
~/workspace/samples
```

This means that the sample folder will be the main repository *(something like a container)*,
for example I would like to have the following structure:

```
$ mkdir sample-java
$ mkdir sample-c-plus-plus
$ mkdir sample-csharp
$ ls -l
total 3
drwxr-xr-x  juanca  staff  408 Mar 30 20:04 sample-java
drwxr-xr-x  juanca  staff  408 Mar 30 20:12 sample-c-plus-plus
drwxr-xr-x  juanca  staff  408 Mar 30 20:23 sample-csharp
```

I want a repo for each folder listed above, in my github account, for example:

```
|- samples -----------------> github.com/my-user/samples.git
    |- sample-java ---------> github.com/my-user/samples.git/sample-java.git
    |- sample-c-plus-plus --> github.com/my-user/samples.git/sample-c-plus-plus.git
    |- sample-csharp -------> github.com/my-user/samples.git/sample-csharp.git
```

I would like to have control in each `sample-*` folder and in turn all of them grouped in a main repository.

Is it possible? Or what would be the best approach?

I found something similar with git submodule, but this adds an existing repo, for example:

```
$ git submodule add https:// github.com/any-account/any-project.git any-project
```

I do not think this solution works for me. Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

> I found something similar with git submodule, but this adds an existing repo.

This is actually the solution.

Each of your sub-repo should be individual repos of their own (ie, directly under  `github.com/my-user`).
That way, you can declare them as submodule of your main repo

```
cd samples
git submodule add github.com/my-user/sample-java.git sample-java
git submodule add github.com/my-user/sample-c-plus-plusgit sample-c-plus-plus
git submodule add github.com/my-user/csharp.git sample-csharp
```

That way:

- any `git clone --recursive` of the repo `samples` would automatically clone and checkout those sub-repos at their respective SHA1.
- any modification done in each repo can be tracked indivisually, added and committed (and pushed) to its own repo.

Comment: Is it means that should I have one repo for each `sample-*` folder and another `main` repo that has references to each of the other `sample-*` repositories?

I imagine the following scenario:

If I had the `github.com/my-user/samples.git` and `github.com/my-user/sample-java.git` repositories, when I will do `git submodule add github.com/my-user/sample-java.git sample-java` on `samples` repo, would I have duplicate repositories, don't I? 

I think the `sample-java` repo will be the same repo inside the `samples` repo (something a duplicate repo, it's confusing).

Comment: @JUANCALVOPINAM you won't have a duplicate: only a reference to an existing repo. It does not duplicate. It only allows you to work in sample-java from within the main parent repo sample.